# Post to Facebook groups without member-freinds being notified of it?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-groups, friends, facebook-notifications

Can I post to Facebook groups without my freinds (members of that group) being notified of it?
Everytime I post to a group, they get notifications that I just posted something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow you to do that. You'll either have to post from another account, or post to groups they are not members of.